# How to convert D3 time scale from V3 to V4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to convert this code from **V3** of D3.js to **V4** version :

```
var monthArray = d3.time.scale()
                .domain(d3.extent(metricMonths))
                .ticks(d3.time.months, 1);
```

Comment: What does the documentation say about migration?

Comment: thank you very much , but if i understand this and i find this in the documentation , iw ll not post a question

Comment: That's not always true. People post questions about many topics without reading the documentation for them first.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the snippet will work for **D3 V4**:

```js
const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(2020, 0, 1), new Date(2020, 11, 1)])
    .range([0, 500]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale)
    .ticks(12)
    .tickFormat(d => months[d.getMonth()])

const svg = d3.select("svg")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,30)")
    .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100" />
```

**UPD**: This code will also work as well:

```
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 11])
        .range([0, 500]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(xScale)
        .ticks(12)
        .tickFormat(d => months[d])
```